# Definition of a natural number in ZF set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In "Elements of Set Theory" by Herbert B. Enderton pg. 10, 68, and 69

> For advanced works in set theory, the Zermelo-Frankel alternative seems to be the better of the two. It profits from the simplicity of having to deal with only one sort of object (sets) instead of two (classes and sets). ... We officially adopt the Zermelo-Frankel alternative. Consequently the axioms and theorems shall make no mention of any class that is not a set. But in the expository comments, we will not hesitate to mention, say, the class of all sets if it appears helpful to do so.

> **Definition** $\;\;$A *natural number* is a set that belongs to every inductive set.

> In terms of classes, we have
> $$\omega = \bigcap\{A\;|\;A \text{ is inductive}\},$$
> but the class of all inductive sets is not a set.

The author says "axioms and theorems shall make no mention of any class that is not a set". But in the definition of natural number isn't "every inductive set" a class which is not a set?

Comment: I believe the last quote you give (mentioning classes) is one of the "expository notes". The definition can be quite happily formalised as "$x$ is a natural number if, $\forall Y$, $Y$ inductive $\implies$ $x \in Y$." That the set of natural numbers is a set remains to be proved, however.

Comment: @preferred_anon But the domain of $Y$ would be a class of all inductive sets. If so, we still have to consider "class" in the definition.

Comment: Not the case. Universal quantifiers are mere syntax. You can quantify over the whole universe if you want. You just can't use it as a set.

Comment: Every inductive set is a ...  set, but the *class* of all inductive sets is not a set. That means: there is no set of all inductive sets (no reference to *classes* at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in saying  that the class of all inductive sets is not a set, however when we write: $$\omega = \bigcap\{A\;|\;A \text{ is inductive}\}$$ What we mean is that $\omega$ is the (unique) set, which is a subset of **all** inductive sets. In a formula: $$\forall x[x\in \omega \iff \forall I ( \text{Inductive}(I)\implies x\in I)]$$
Of course one still has to prove that, such a $\omega$ exists, (*Just like you have to prove the existence of any other set*)but the existence follows easily from the **axiom of infinity**. Take a look at the Wikipedia page for a sketch: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity.